# Generating Visual Studio project files for cpp-ethereum

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, ethereum

I want to generate Visual Studio files by [this](http://ethdocs.org/en/latest/ethereum-clients/cpp-ethereum/building-from-source/windows.html) instructions, and when I use the commands:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -G "Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64" ..
```

it says :

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:44 <project>:
Failed to run MSBuild command:
c:/Program files <x86>/MSBuild/14.0/bin/MSBuild.exe
to get the value of VCTargetspath:
Microsoft <R> Build Engine version 14.0.25420.1
Copyright <c? Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved
MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist.
Switch: VCITargetspath.vcxproj

Exit code: 1
Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also c:/Windows/System32/cpp-ethereum/build/CMakefiles/CMakeOutput.log
```

and also when I use the alt command:

```
cmake --build . --config RelWithDebInfo
```

it says:

```
MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist.
Switch: ALL_BUILD.vcxproj
```

I have to note that I have git, CMake and Visual Studio 2015 Professional fully installed.

Comment: Do you have the file `c:/Program files <x86>/MSBuild/14.0/bin/MSBuild.exe` which is noted in the error message? Also, what is content of the log `c:/Windows/System32/cpp-ethereum/build/CMakefiles/CMakeOutput.log`?

Comment: It is strange that you are getting log in `c:/Windows/System32/cpp-ethereum`. Where do you run these commands from?

Comment: Yes i do have the MSBuild.exe file! And the content on the log file is "The system is: Windows - 6.1.7601 - AMD64" @Tsyvarev ------------------------------------I run commands from CMD

Comment: The fact that you have log file under `c:/Windows/System32/cpp-ethereum/build` means that you attempt to build the project under **system directory**. This should be avoided by any means.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I just followed the instructions.

Comment: Instructions suggest you to *clone* the project. But they forgot that `cmd` opens terminal with `C:\Windows\System32` as current directory... Anyway, it is better to clone the project to other directory (e.g., under user's home directory), and repeate the building.

Comment: You should start a Visual Studio 14 2015 Developer Command Prompt first and execute all the necessary commands from there. see following [link] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/developer-command-prompt-for-vs) how to do it.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Well.... I tried that and got the same error at the last step :(

Comment: @vre What commands do you mean exatcly?

Comment: Those commands you previously typed into the default console. The Developer Command Prompt adds a bunch of environment variables that are needed to run MSBuild.exe and cl.exe and other programs. Performing the instructions from your [this](http://ethdocs.org/en/latest/ethereum-clients/cpp-ethereum/building-from-source/windows.html) link in this command prompt should then give correct build results.